# Views: What setting is available in Views to hide or skip the first entry in a multi-value field? (example skip first image)

Tags: views, media

On my site, I have created an "Images" field with "unlimited" values. I have used "image delta=0" to show only the first image as the main gallery image. I then created a grid with a contextual filter of "content: nid" to display up to 10 of the images in that field. I would like to now hide the first image from the output, so that it isn't repeated with the first/main image on the page.

I have the contextual reference working well, but I haven't been able to figure out how to skip the first image. I tried a playing around with the Image Delta settings "=1", assuming that this means to increment by 1, but when I save, my view is empty.

I'm sure this is straight forward, but I have come up empty in my attempts (literally) and searches.

Thanks,
keb
[image: Views Settings]
[image: Field Settings]

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remembered doing this in a Views tutorial and remembered it was a control located within the center region of the Views interface.

Turns out it's under "Pager": Use pager: Display a specified number of items >> "You may also adjust the **settings** for the currently selected pager"

Click **setttings** and you'll be able to add an offset.

[image: Pager Setting]

[image: Pager Settings Click]

[image: Pager Offset Setting]